# OnInit list not displaying

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I'm creating an Angular6 crud app and I have a list of users in my database.  I am able to retrieve my list when I call getAllUsers but it does not display in the UI. The only time I see a row being displayed in the table is when I manually enter a new User but it does not display the data previous to my entry.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDataService } from './user-data.service';
import { User } from './user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [UserDataService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  users: User[]=[];

  constructor(private userDataService: UserDataService) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    debugger
      this.userDataService
        .getAllUsers()
        .subscribe(
          (users) => {
            this.users = users;
          }
        );

  }

  onAddUser(user) {
    this.userDataService
      .addUser(user)
      .subscribe(
        (newUser) => {
          this.users = this.users.concat(newUser);
        }
      )
  }

  onRemoveUser(user){
    this.userDataService
      .deleteUserById(user.id)
      .subscribe(
        (_) => {
          this.users = this.users.filter((u) => u.id !== user.id);
        }
      );
  }

  getUser() {
    return this.userDataService.getAllUsers();
  }
}
```

APP COMPONENT HTML

```
  <app-user-list-header (add)="onAddUser($event)"></app-user-list-header>


  <table>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <tr *ngFor = "let user of users">
      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
      <td>{{user.userName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

USER DATA SERVICE

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './user';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserDataService {

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  addUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.api.createUser(user);
  }

  getAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.api.getAllUsers();
  }

  updateUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.api.updateUser(user);
  }

  getUserById(userId: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.api.getUserById(userId);
  }

  deleteUserById(userId: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.api.deleteUserById(userId);
  }
}
```

USER LIST HEADER

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../user';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list-header',
  templateUrl: './user-list-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list-header.component.css']
})
export class UserListHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  newUser: User = new User();

  @Output()
  add: EventEmitter<User> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addUser() {
    this.add.emit(this.newUser);
    this.newUser = new User();
  }
}
```

USER LIST HEADER HTML

```
<header class="userHeader">
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <input class="new-user" placeholder="Enter User" autofocus="" [(ngModel)]="newUser.userName" (keyup.enter)="addUser()">
</header>
```

API SERVICE

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

    import { User } from './user';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { map, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";


const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  public createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    const headers = {headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })};
    return this.http
     .post(API_URL + '/users', user).pipe(
        map(response => {
          return new User(response);
        }), catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }

  public getAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(API_URL + '/users').pipe(
      map(response => {
        var users = [response];
        return users.map((user)=> new User(user));
      }), catchError(this.handleError))
  }
```

Comment: where `TaskDataService` is imported from ? i feel like there is an incompleteness.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the console?

Comment: can you show the code of the userDataService.getAllUsers()?

Comment: also where is the directive `app-user-list-header` located in your ts app ?

Comment: added header and user data service. I removed task data because it's not implemented.

Comment: @MSkiLLz try to replace `let user of users` by `let user of getUser()`

Comment: @Abra001 No luck. It shows this error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: ok does this error show after the last edit ? or it was before ?

Comment: after the last edit putting in getUser()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171276/discussion-between-mskillz-and-abra001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, you don't need to subcribe a new user to the observable here in the AppComponent again after you have done it before:

```
   .subscribe(
     (newUser) => {
        this.users = this.users.concat(newUser);
     }
   )
```

because it is already added to the user array by this mean: `this.userDataService.addUser(user)`, that says you inserted the same value twice to the observer.

So what you need to do is, in the userdata service, plug an observer to the rest api that fetches data regularily to the adapter `getAllUsers` like this:

```
  getAllUsers(): Observable<user[]> {
    // some intermediate post call happens here
    this.api.getAllUsers().subscribe((users) => users.map((user)=>this.users.push(user)));
    return of(this.users);
  }
```

This will update the state of users whenever a new value added to the users base, or piped from the rest call, so you do **never have to subcribe the same value more than once from the same observer**, this will cause duplication of data.

I couldn't find an online api that allows post calls, so you could find your ease figuring that I said above using your own tools, but for a same-domain GET api service, I made an example in this term visible to your eyes here:

[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rndqsd](https://angular-rndqsd.stackblitz.io).
Taking countries as users for sake of vocabulary-allowance.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  After this change, my new users aren't being listed.  The initial problem is still there. I have data in my json object but on page load (ngOnInit), it does not display the data.  It only displays the data entered.

Comment: so as i understood you well, you want to inject user twice to the observable and initial array ? this will cause abandance of data?

Comment: When I restart my backend API, I have no data. Then in the UI, I enter new users (User 1 and User 2) in my header input. This stores the users in the server.  When I reload the UI, User 1 and User 2, are not displaying in the table anymore. But if I type User 3, it displays User 3 with an id of 3. Meaning User 1 and User 2 are still there but they don't display.  I need to get user 1 and user 2 to display on UI reload.

Comment: @MSkiLLz the data is initiated well, see again plz. You can see that two users "foo" and "bar" previously present in `user-data.service` are stowed initialy in the table. If you add a new user, the grid would be filled with one more.

Comment: I'm not sure what changes you are suggesting for me to do. According to your answer, it looks like you want me to change the newUser function in app component? But I thought the problem is in my getUsers function

Comment: @MSkiLLz getusers works pretty fine, maybe you couldnt know how to use it, compare your work with my demo and report me things that arent working.

Comment: @MSkiLLz according to your data you are importing users from some unknown somewhere returned from an api, me, i added them in a simple json wrapper to facilitate my task because the question is not about a functionality of an api.

Comment: @MSkiLLz btw, you forgot to use `of()` in all where an observable object returns a value, doesnt this fire an error to you ?